# Migrating Windows Server 2008 R2 Hyper-V machines to Windows 8 Hyper-V

Tags: windows-8, hyper-v

I was using Windows Server 2008 R2 as my developer machine, hosting my Hyper-V virtual machines.  I am now switching over to Windows 8 to run Hyper-V in a client OS, which is my use case anyway.

Are there any gotchas I should be aware of before I attempt to port my existing VMs into Windows 8 Hyper-V?  I have a few virtual machines on a virtual network, and I need them to continue working (DC, SQL, SharePoint, etc).  Are there any special steps I should take (for instance, exporting my virtual network instead of recreating a new one) to minimize headaches?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hyper-V for Windows 8 is a newer version of Hyper-V (V3) than Hyper-V for Server 2008.  It is not recommended to import VM's created from Windows 8 to Server 2008.  However going from Server 2008 to Windows 8 has no problems.  If you MUST migrate from Windows 8 to Server 2008 Hyper-V make sure to NOT use the .vhdx files.

### Converting .VHD & .VHDX:

1. Open Hyper-V
2. Right click on the VM that you wish to convert, and select Settings:

   [image: Settings]
3. Select the Hard Drive IDE (usually IDE 0) and then select "Edit":

   [image: Settings: Edit]
4. Select Convert, and then Next
5. Select the type of VHD you wish to convert to and then Next
6. Select the type of disk: (Fixed Size, Dynamically Expanding) and then Next
7. Select the location (NOTE: This does NOT default to last saved location) and then Next
8. Select Finish

---

The use of exporting and importing is [the preferred way of migrating VM's](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/da-DK/winserverhyperv/thread/9446073a-0f97-4925-abbc-0c19875716f0) between Machines (Server 2008 to Windows 8 in your case).

To do this follow these steps:

## Exporting:

1. Open Hyper-V Terminal
2. Right click on the VM that you want to export and select "Export" (make sure the machine is turned off):

   [image: Export]
3. Browse to the folder that you wish to save the VM:

   [image: Browsing]
4. Then Select Export.

Hyper-V will then in the background export the VM.  This may take a few minutes or even quite a bit of time, depending on the type and size of the VM.

## Importing:

1. Open Hyper-V Terminal
2. On the right side, under the "Action" panel select "Import Virtual Machine...":

   [image: Actions Panel]
3. Select Next
4. Browse to the folder where you saved the VM
5. Select the Exported VM:

   [image: Selection]
6. Select whether you want to Register, Restore, or Copy the VM

   > - **Register:** If you have a virtual machine were you have already put all of the virtual machine files exactly where you want them, and
   >   you just need Hyper-V to start using the virtual machine where it is –
   >   this is the option you want to choose.
   > - **Restore:** If your virtual machine files are stored on a file share / removable drive / etc… and you want Hyper-V to move the files
   >   to the appropriate location for you, and then register the virtual
   >   machine – this is the option for you.
   > - **Copy:** If you have a set of virtual machine files that you want to import multiple times (e.g. you are using them as a template
   >   for new virtual machines) this is what you want to choose.  This will
   >   copy the files to an appropriate location, give the virtual machine a
   >   new unique ID, and then register the virtual machine.
7. Select Finish

This will import the VM into Hyper-V.  Again, this may take some time depending on the type/size of the VM and the options selected above.

Comment: Great answer.  Thank you.  Is there anything I should do for the networks?

Comment: @NathanDeWitt what do you mean exactly?

Comment: I have a virtual network for the VMs to use between themselves.  Do I just create a new one in Win8 or should I somehow export the one I use currently?

Comment: There's probably going to be some configuration that you'll have to do, but anything that is done withing the VM's themselves will stay the same.  Virtual switches however, I don't believe are exported.